# How do you change opacity in love2d?

Tags: love2d

Does anybody know how to change the opacity in love2d?
I'm making a game and I want to draw the title first as transparent and then make it more and more visible. (Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the opacity by specifying an alpha in `love.graphics.setColor()` function. Check this out: https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.setColor